# Firefox not sending request after response 500

Tags: spring, angular, firefox, angular5

As you guys can see below when I am trying to upload a file XLSX into my API in Firefox, if XLSX does not have all columns that I need to map it to a class, I will throw an Exception and it will return a status 500. If I do not change the file I will get error 500 infinite times. Like below[image]

After some requests it does not send anymore. And it only happens when I change the file, the 4th request below should return status 200. When I debug my application in spring it is not even entering the endpoint.

[image]

In Chrome I do not have this problem, I can sent a lot of requests and the behavior is different. Do you guys know if firefox has some security to prevent multiple requests like this? If I reload the page and send the 4th request alone it will return status 200.

I am using Angular 5 + Spring Boot